# Using boost's skewed_normal_distribution

Tags: c++, boost, distribution, skew

I am fairly new to c++ and boost.

I want to create a set of numbers that derived from a skewed distribution using Boost's `skewed_normal_distribution` class.

I'm not sure how to even start. I want to define a distribution with mean 0.05, variance 0.95, but a skew of 0.5. The following code doesn't work and I realise I need to set up a `variate_generator` as well.

Can anyone provide some pointers? I am not finding the boost documentation page on `skew_normal_distribution` very intuitive but that might be because of my inexperience.

Note the main problem I am getting is the message:

‘`skew_normal_distribution`’ is not a member of ‘`boost`’

Many thanks

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>

#include <boost/math/distributions/skew_normal.hpp>

int main () {
    boost::skew_normal_distribution<> normal(0.05, 0.95, 0.5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::math::skew_normal_distribution` instead of `boost::skew_normal_distribution` for the message

> `skew_normal_distribution` is not a member of `boost`