# Using Boost skew_normal_distribution

Tags: c++, boost, normal-distribution, skew

This has been addressed before ([Using boost's skewed_normal_distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185604/using-boosts-skewed-normal-distribution)) but I having difficulties and the previous thread didn't include any solution code.

I would like to sample from a skewed normal distribution using the functions built into the Boost library

I am adapting code that I know works fine with the `normal_distribution<>` class but when I run the code I keep getting the error shown below.  If anyone could help me with this I'd be very grateful.

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/skew_normal.hpp>

int main() {

boost::mt19937 rng2;

boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<> snd(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,
        boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<> > var_snd(rng2, snd);

int i = 0; for (; i < 10; ++i)
{
    double d = var_snd();
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/random.hpp:55:0,
                 from /home/jack/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class boost::random::variate_generator<boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615u, 11ul, 4294967295u, 7ul, 2636928640u, 15ul, 4022730752u, 18ul, 1812433253u>&, boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<double> >’:
/home/jack/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:13:63:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp:59:48: error: no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘class boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<double>’
     typedef typename Distribution::result_type result_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different namespaces in Boost which both contain distribution classes: `boost::random` and `boost::math`. Unfortunately these two different namespaces are written with different purposes in mind and therefore, the underlying distributions cannot be immediately interchanged as you're trying to do here.

You'll notice that the normal distribution class you originally started with belongs to the `boost::random` namespace. Whilst the `skew_normal` class belongs to the `boost::math` namespace; hence the incompatibility.

If you simply wish to generate samples from a `boost::math::skew_normal` distribution however, you are able to do so using the following method (assuming you're using C++11):

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/skew_normal.hpp>

// Setup generators
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine noise_generator;

// Sample from a uniform distribution i.e. [0,1)
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_dist(0,1.0);

// Take a different value every time to generate probabilities from 0 to 1
noise_generator.seed(rd());
auto probability = uniform_dist(noise_generator);

auto skew_norm_dist = boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<double>(
    0, 1., 10.);

// Use the probability from the uniform distribution with the percent point
// function of the skew_normal
double skew_normal_sample_point = boost::math::quantile(skew_norm_dist, probability);
std::cout << "Sample point: " << skew_normal_sample_point << std::endl;
```

Here you're essentially generating a probability value from a uniform distribution and then using this to lookup a value from the `skew_normal_distribution`'s percent point function.

If you put these last four lines in a loop and produce a large number of points e.g.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    noise_generator.seed(rd());
    auto probability = uniform_dist(noise_generator);
    double skew_normal_sample_point = boost::math::quantile(skew_norm_dist, probability);
    std::cout << skew_normal_sample_point << std::endl;
}
```

and then plot the results in a histogram, you'll see they conform to the skewed normal distribution you created.

Comment: Why do you feed value generated from `rd` into `noise_generator`? Can't you use it directly?